# How to make Xcode project folder location independent

Tags: xcode

There must be something wrong with the way I build my project.

I noticed that when I move my Xcode project folder from a directory inside my document folder to the desktop for example, it doesn't build when it previously does! In my case this time, somehow it can't find the Core Plot sub project.

It says:
`clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/t2wu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HRM-fxvjidgvnxghjogeevqdzlccbulu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a'`

Any pointer appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your current error `clean` should help

Use macro `$(SOURCE_ROOT)` for any third party library.

Comment: I tried clean and I also cleaned out derived data directory as well. It doesn't work. Also for header directory I used relative paths.

Comment: I think it's linking that's the problem. But I don't know exactly what.

Comment: `libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a` is subproject that you added as target dependency ?

Comment: Yeah I think I missed that. Thanks.